# SQL Server: Is there any way to prevent accidental multiple updates of the same row in a single UPDATE Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When you write an `UPDATE` statement from a join of two or more tables, there is always a possibility that you accidentally omitted one condition and it may end up updating the same row multiple times and lead to unexpected results, especially when there are complex keys/relationships.

Is there any way to ENSURE that if such situation happens, SQL Server raises an error or gives some kind of warning?

I'm usually careful on those things, but it happened to me few times recently, when I was trying to retrieve data from a not well known to me Database with complex relationships inside.

While my question is about SQL Server, how to prevent this situation, I'd be glad to hear how do you make sure its not happening?

Here is a small made up example of what I mean:

```
DECLARE @Customers TABLE (Id INT, Name VARCHAR(100), LatestInvoice VARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @Orders TABLE (Id INT, CustomerId INT, Invoice VARCHAR(100), Date DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @Customers (Id, Name)
VALUES (1, 'Customer1')

INSERT INTO @Orders (Id, CustomerId, Invoice, Date)
VALUES (1, 1, 'Invoice 1', '1/1/2019'),
       (2, 1, 'Invoice 2', '2/1/2019'),
       (3, 1, 'Invoice 3', '3/1/2019')

-- Correct UPDATE
-- one record updates once
UPDATE C
SET LatestInvoice = O.Invoice
FROM @Customers C 
JOIN @Orders O ON O.CustomerId = C.Id
WHERE O.Date = '3/1/2019'

-- Incorrect UPDATE
-- one record gets updated 3 times and result of Invoice could be anything
UPDATE C
SET LatestInvoice = O.Invoice
FROM @Customers C 
JOIN @Orders O ON O.CustomerId = C.Id
```

And BTW, how is such UPDATE mistake called?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no setting that will allow the engine to abort a nondeterministic `UPDATE`. There is built-in protection against this sort of thing in `MERGE`, but I'm not sure if it's 100% guaranteed to always catch all attempts at updating a row twice. It is generally possible to rewrite the query so this cannot happen by exploiting the fact that it's illegal to have an assignment subquery return multiple values (`UPDATE @Customers SET LatestInvoice = (SELECT Invoice FROM @Orders O WHERE O.CustomerID = [@Customers].ID)`, use `WITH` for complicated cases) but this is hard to do consistently.

Comment: In my situation I have multiple fields updated in the same UPDATE statement, so assigning (SELECT ... ) unfortunately is not an option. But yes, if it is a single field it will raise an error.

Comment: One way I use quite often: have a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` before the update, then run the code up to and including the `UPDATE`, but **do NOT yet commit!!** and then check if the `UPDATE` did what you expected. If yes: run `COMMIT` and complete the transcation; if not, do a `ROLLBACK` and your `UPDATE` is undone

Comment: Unfortunately when you update 200K records and it gets updated from 201K records its hard visually find the problem. Especially if you don't know the incoming data... But thanks, in case of small number of records it might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` instead of `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE C
    SET LatestInvoice = O.Invoice
FROM @Customers C CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) O.*
      FROM @Orders O 
      WHERE O.CustomerId = C.Id
     ) O;
```

This will update once with an arbitrary matching row.  You can add an `ORDER BY` to the subquery to provide more specification on the row that should be used.

EDIT:

I don't think there is a clean way to do this.  I don't think there is a built-in function that will return an error from a query (such as `throw()` or `raise_error()` in T-SQL code).  You can use the handy divide-by-zero error instead:

```
UPDATE C
    SET LatestInvoice = O.Invoice
FROM @Customers C JOIN
     (SELECT O.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY O.CustomerId) as cnt
      FROM @Orders O 
     ) O
     ON O.CustomerId = C.Id
WHERE (CASE WHEN cnt > 1 THEN 1 / 0 ELSE cnt END) = 1;
```

Comment: I think you mean CROSS APPLY, but in any case the problem is not that I don't know how to ensure that it updates only once (if I know there might be duplicate references), but rather ENSURE that if there are duplicate references, I get error or warning. I don't want to replace all my UPDATEs with above structure :)

Comment: More over I think this solution (CROSS APPLY to TOP 1) will HIDE the problem, rather then highlighting it to me for a correct resolution (to use correct keys and where statements).

Comment: Sorry if it reads that way, but Yes, My intention is to be notified if such situation arise, so I could adjust my 'UPDATE' statement accordingly.

Comment: @tgralex . . . That is a much more interesting question.  I think the answer is "no, there isn't a way" but would like to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% defence, but .. Start designing an UPDATE with a SELECT

```
SELECT target.PrimaryKey, Count(*)
  -- update table expression here
GROUP BY target.PrimaryKey
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

For example

```
SELECT C.id, Count(*)
-- update table expression here
FROM @Customers C 
JOIN @Orders O ON O.CustomerId = C.Id
-- 
GROUP BY C.id
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks Serg, That certainly will help, but was hoping that MS SQL could have have an internal mechanism to prevent mentioned problem.

Comment: But it certainly a good way of catching the problem when you design a single UPDATE statement. Not sure how helpful this could be if that UPDATE is in the middle of a SP and using results of prior statements...

Comment: @tgralex: it sort of has a prevention mechanism -- the optimizer may arrange things so every row only gets updated once, by restricting the input data. The final result is still nondeterministic in that it picks "any" row for the source, but rows will not actually get updated multiple times. Rearranging the query to actually detect the issue and stop is more complicated, and would make for a less efficient plan. Having an option to make it go the extra mile would occasionally be worthwhile, but, well, not free. It could be a [feature](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think it doesn't prevent automatically, you need to convert your UPDATE statement to analogue SELECT with GROUP BY over your primary key and add HAVING Count()*) > 1 to see if anything filters out (that would be a multiple reference). And if no results, consider running your UPDATE. Its great if it is a single statement.

Comment: @tgralex: In my tests (SQL Server 2017 RTM CU15) the optimizer produces a plan that will only update the row once, despite having three input rows from the `JOIN`, by means of a `Stream Aggregate` operation. `@@ROWCOUNT` is `1` after the query, not `3`. The net effect is still a non-deterministic update, of course. I have not gone so far as to test what happens with disk-based tables and an `UPDATE` trigger, and I don't imagine that this behavior would be universal as the query gets more complicated (you can't count on any particular behavior for this). This is what I mean with "sort of".

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I noticed it updates once too, but certainly the problem here is the non-deterministic update result caused by the incorrect conditions in ON and WHERE in the statement...

Comment: @JeroenMostert It's my impession too. Sqlsever internaly "swallows" candidate updates but one and updates the target once.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like if you have an `UPDATE` which might have multiple references to a target table rows, is the best to use 'MERGE' instead of 'UPDATE'

> Unlike non-deterministic UPDATE the standard MERGE statement will
>   generates an error if multiple source rows match one target row,
>   requiring to revise the code to make it deterministic.

Here is the conversion of above `UPDATE` to the `MERGE` statement and the second one actually errors out!

```
-- works just fine
MERGE @Customers T
USING @Orders S
ON S.CustomerId = T.Id AND S.Date = '3/1/2019'
WHEN MATCHED
THEN 
    UPDATE SET LatestInvoice = S.Invoice;


-- omitting Date condition will follow with this error:
-- The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.
MERGE @Customers T
USING @Orders S
ON S.CustomerId = T.Id --AND S.Date = '3/1/2019'
WHEN MATCHED
THEN 
    UPDATE SET LatestInvoice = S.Invoice;
```

Still, I think MS SQL should have have at least an option for the UPDATE statement to fail in non-deterministic updates as it certainly a mistake and leads to problems.